# EGOTableViewPullRefresh crash when over-releasing the view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, pull-to-refresh

I embedded in my project **EGOTableViewPullRefresh**, everything works and updates fine, but when I pull the view down too much to update, app crashes with the error:

> 2012-04-24 19:02:56.670 Test [3927: f803] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** - [__NSArrayM
>   objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array'
>   *** First throw call stack:

the piece of code

```
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
NSMutableArray * viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


//plist file full path
NSString *urlStr = [[NSString alloc] 
                    initWithFormat:@"http://www.test.com/data.xml?seedVar=%f", 
                    (float)random()/RAND_MAX];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

  //Get the folder array
NSArray * subscriptionFolders = [dict objectForKey:@"Folders"];
```

**UPDATE**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setNumberOfLines:3];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }

    RSSItem * rssItem = (RSSItem *)[_rssParser.rssItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:rssItem.title];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:rssItem.summary];

    return cell;
}
```

can you help me with this?

Comment: I don't see any array here. So you are crashing somewhere else... See where you are accessing an array in your code. Since you are mentioning a EGOTableVIew, I would guess you are crashin in the tableview datasource cellForRowAtIndexPath function

Comment: you mean this? see updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. When I called **rssParser** in **reloadTableViewDataSource** it crash. When I tryed to call **rssParser** in **dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData** all works fine without crash.

```
- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource{
[super performSelector:@selector(dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}

- (void)dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData{
    [_rssParser start];
    [refreshHeaderView setCurrentDate]; 
    [super dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData];   
}
```